# Spring boot embedded LDAP fails to authenticate the user

Tags: ldap

I am trying to auth the user with springboot embedded ldap but getting following error.

[image]

```
public class SpringSecurityLDAP {

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin();

    return http.build();
}

@Autowired
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
            .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
            .contextSource()
            .url("ldap://localhost:8389/dc=springframework,dc=org")
            .and()
            .passwordCompare()
            .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
            .passwordAttribute("userPassword");


 }
}
```

Following tutorial from this link: https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/

Comment: @EnableSpringSecurity was added on the class. i tried with user:ben and Pass:benspassword (suggested in spring tutorial) but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing @Configuration on top of SpringSecurityLDAP class.
Do not forget to add these properties as well:-

```
spring.ldap.embedded.ldif=classpath:test-server.ldif
spring.ldap.embedded.base-dn=dc=springframework,dc=org
spring.ldap.embedded.port=8389
```

I have been able to successfully use embedded LDAP for authentication. For more details, refer to this [git example](https://github.com/AnuragMishra58/spring-security-examples/blob/main/ldap-example/src/main/java/com/anurag/ldapexample/config/WebSecurityConfig.java)

Comment: Thanks Anurag!! I'll verify your solution and give my feedback in comments. if all goes well i'll mark your response as accepted.